# what is wrong with my code for code jam 2015

Tags: c++

Here the question

At the Infinite House of Pancakes, there are only finitely many pancakes, but there are infinitely many diners who would be willing to eat them! When the restaurant opens for breakfast, among the infinitely many diners, exactly D have non-empty plates; the ith of these has Pi pancakes on his or her plate. Everyone else has an empty plate.

Normally, every minute, every diner with a non-empty plate will eat one pancake from his or her plate. However, some minutes may be special. In a special minute, the head server asks for the diners' attention, chooses a diner with a non-empty plate, and carefully lifts some number of pancakes off of that diner's plate and moves those pancakes onto one other diner's (empty or non-empty) plate. No diners eat during a special minute, because it would be rude.

You are the head server on duty this morning, and it is your job to decide which minutes, if any, will be special, and which pancakes will move where. That is, every minute, you can decide to either do nothing and let the diners eat, or declare a special minute and interrupt the diners to make a single movement of one or more pancakes, as described above.

Breakfast ends when there are no more pancakes left to eat. How quickly can you make that happen?
Input

The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each consists of one line with D, the number of diners with non-empty plates, followed by another line with D space-separated integers representing the numbers of pancakes on those diners' plates.
Output

For each test case, output one line containing "Case #x: y", where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the smallest number of minutes needed to finish the breakfast.
Limits

1 ≤ T ≤ 100.
Small dataset

1 ≤ D ≤ 6.
1 ≤ Pi ≤ 9.
Large dataset

1 ≤ D ≤ 1000.
1 ≤ Pi ≤ 1000.

Sample

Input

```
3
1
3
4
1 2 1 2
1
4
```

Output

```
Case #1: 3
Case #2: 2
Case #3: 3
```

and this is my source code

```
int result = 0, D = 0;

int part(vector<int> v1) {

    if(v1[D - 1] == 0)
        return 0;

    int t1 = 0, t2 = 0, t3 = 0, i = 0;
    vector<int> v2;

    for(i = 0; i < D; ++i)
        if(v1[i])
            v2.push_back(v1[i] - 1);
        else
            v2.push_back(0);

    if(v1[D - 1] == 1)
        v1[D - 1] = 0;

    else if( v1[D-1] % 2 )
        v1[ D- 1 ] = ( v1[D-1] / 2 ) + 1;

    else
        v1[ D -1 ] = v1[ D - 1 ] / 2;

    sort(v1.begin(),v1.end());

    t1 = 1 + part(v1);
    t2 = 1 + part(v2);
    t3 = min(t1,t2);
    return t3;


}

int main(void) {



    int T = 0, count = 0;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    while(T--) {

        vector<int> v1;
        vector<int> ::iterator it;
        int i = 0, temp = 0; D = 0;
        result = 0;
        ++count;

        scanf("%d",&D);
        for(i = 0; i < D; ++i) {
             scanf("%d",&temp);
            v1.push_back(temp);
        }
        sort( v1.begin(), v1.end() );

        result = part(v1);




        printf("Case #%d: %d\n",count,result);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know. What *is* wrong with this?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your program in the debugger to see where it goes wrong?

Comment: Are you assuming that the stack must be split in half each time? The best solution for 1 stack with 9 pancakes is 5, because you split it twice, into 3 piles of 3.

Comment: Yes I am getting 5 for the test case 9

Comment: I have compared my output for test cases file with a accepted solution now and out of 100 test cases I am getting wrong result in 3 test cases

Comment: What will be the result of 7 pancakes and 8 pancakes?

Comment: the answer would be 6 minutes -  4min +2 special mins

Comment: okay I got my mistake

Comment: :( How stupid I am :(
7 = (7 / 2 ) 4 and 3   then I divide 4 / 2 = 2 and 2 so stack is 2,2,3 and I forget to take care of 3 :(

Comment: as said above diving by 2 wont solve it in case of 9

Comment: I am getting right answer on 9 but I am wrong on 7